# Reducing the number of queries in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a Django app that tracks awards that a person receives. Below is a simplified representation of two models that I have:

```
class AwardHolder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def get_total_awards(self):
        entries = self.award_set.all()
        calc = entries.aggregate(sum=Sum('units_awarded'))
        return calc.get('sum') or 0


class Award(models.Model)
    date_awarded = models.DateField()
    units_awarded = models.IntegerField()
    award_holder = models.ForeignKey(AwardHolder)
```

I created a summary page for the award holder where he can see his total awards. I use the `get_total_awards` function above. That all works well, but then I created an overview page to display the total awards per award holder. I use the function below to get the total awards per award holder:

```
def get_all_awards():
    qs = AwardHolder.objects.all()
    awards = []
    for ah in qs:
        awards.append((ah, ah.get_total_awards())
    return awards
```

This generates a large number of queries since it hits the db every loop. Is there a way I can use `prefetch_related` or some other db trick to reduce the number of db queries, without having to rewrite `get_all_awards()`?

The actual code I use has a lot more fields and is more complicated than this example. There's about 10 functions similar to `get_all_awards()`, so rewriting it will be quite some work. However, for 100 award holders my code generated a whopping 18000 queries, so I know I have to fix this somehow.

Comment: I think this is a job for annotate rather than aggregate. Something like `AwardHolder.objects.annotate(Count('award__units_awarded'))`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that since I would have to redo a lot of function. I guess the get_total_awards function inside AwardHolder would still apply if I only want the number of awards for a single award holder?

Comment: For a single award holder that function is perfect unless you can somehow have less that 1 query :P  
For larger numbers it's better to do everything in a single query rather than loop and perform multiple queries, but you will need to test if `annotate` indeed does what I think it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a model manager to always annotate `AwardHolders`

```
class AwardHolderQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def all(self):
        return self.annotate(Count('award__units_awarded'))

class AwardHolder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    objects = AwardHolderQuerySet.as_manager()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_all_awards` does not necessarily have to call `get_total_awards`. You're repeating the same query for each entity instead of using a functionality Django already provides: `annotate`.

You can modify `get_all_awards` to use `annotate` and use `get_total_awards` only when the award applies to a single entity.

```
def get_all_awards():
    qs = AwardHolder.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('award__units_awarded'))
    awards = []
    for ah in qs:
        awards.append((ah, ah.sum))
    return awards
```

You may even drop the `for` loop and use the result from the queryset `qs` directly.

So you get the advantage of an optimized query when multiple objects and their related objects are being fetched, as opposed to running individual queries for each entity.